# $L(V)$ isomorphism $L(V*)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let be $V$ a vector space with finite dimension over F. Show that $\mathscr{L}(V^{*})\cong \mathscr{L}(V)$.

My attemp was try to show that $\mathscr{L}(V^{*})$ is isomorphic with the space $\matrix{M^{n×n}(F)}$, but i don't know how to start. I know that $Dim(V)$ = $Dim(V^{*})$, but it is sufficient to use that?

Sorry for my english

Comment: It appears that the result follows immediately from that $V\cong V^*$: both spaces are over the same field $F$, and they have the same dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linear algebra book we learn that if $V$ is a finite $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$, then $\mathscr L(V)$ is isomorphic to $M_n(F)$. Since both $V$ and $V^*$ have the same dimension, say $n$, we have $\mathscr L(V)\cong M_n(F) \cong \mathscr L(V^*)$.

---

EDIT: As a reply to the comment of @Rodrigo Palacios

The isomorphic relation is transitive. Actually  it is an equivalent relation. Suppose $\phi:U\cong V$, $\psi:V \cong W$ are the bijections preserving addition and scalar multiplication. Then we can examine that $\phi\circ\psi:U\to W$ is also a bijection preserving the two operations. This implies $U\cong W$.

Comment: ok, as V and V* have the same dimension, and L(V) is isomorphic to M(F), this implies that L(V*) is isomorphic to M(F) and then L(V)≅L(V*) ?

Comment: @RodrigoPalacios See my edit.

Comment: The only thing that is not clear is if L(V) is isomorphic to M(F), then L(V*) is isomorphic to to M(F), why?

Comment: @RodrigoPalacios ForaL(W) is isomorphic to the space of n*n matrix.

Comment: @RodrigoPalacios For all n-dimensional space W, L(V) is isomorphic to the n*n matrix space. It holds for both V and V*.